# OpenSSH showing different version from installed version on remote connection

Tags: networking, server, ssh, openssh

On my server on digital ocean, I upgraded OpenSSH to version 8.6p1.

```
user@server:~# ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.6p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

But when I check the OpenSSH version from the remote client it is 7.6p1

```
➜ ssh -v aa.xxx.yy.zzz
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
```

I also changed both `/usr/bin/ssh` with symbolic link of `/usr/local/bin/ssh`. I have rebooted my server many times.

```
user@server:~# /usr/bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.6p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018

user@server:~# /usr/local/bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.6p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

## Questions

1. How to fix this?
2. What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you built OpenSSH yourself from source?

You need to update your systemd service file to load your new binary, which is `sshd` for the server, the `ssh` binary is the client.

Either replace `/usr/sbin/sshd` with your new one or edit the service file `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service` and set all sshd paths to reference `/usr/local/sbin/sshd`

Comment: Thanks this worked.